# Loop through all enum values with multiple non unique numbers

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have this `enum`:

```
public enum MyEnum : byte
{
    [CategoryEnum(Category.Color)]
    Red = 1,
    [CategoryEnum(Category.Color)]
    Blue = 2,

    [CategoryEnum(Category.Attributes)]
    Strong = 1,
    [CategoryEnum(Category.Attributes)]
    Weak = 2
}
```

When I try to do

```
var foo = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>()
```

it will return a list like

```
{Blue, Blue, Red, Red}
```

and that's not what I'm looking for. How can I retreive the *actual values* I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: by using 2 dfferent enums ... Why you wana use one?

Comment: An enum with multiple names with the same value. Kinda strange. But.. what about `var foo = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum));`?

Comment: @MongZhu thats not what im looking for, because i want to get ```{Red, Blue, Strong, Weak}``` as an array of MyEnum

Comment: You will not get that. Enums are value types and their identity is defined by the underlying value (in your case `byte`). `Strong` is nothing more than an alias for `Red` (or vice versa). The closest you can get is something like a `Dictionary<string, byte>` to map between the names and their values. Your `enum` design is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: You might consider using flags if you really want to use one enum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netstandard-2.0, but your values would still need to change to various bit values

Comment: There is no way you can obtain two enum *values* that knows whether they're `Red` or `String`, as an example. That's not how enums work. You can, however, obtain the unique names, regardless of the underlying value. This will be of type string, however, so likely not what you want, but then you can't get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain all the `enum`s names and filter those which match the `value`

**Code:**

```
private static string LongName<T>(long value) where T : Enum {
  unchecked {
    return string.Join(" or ", Enum
      .GetNames(typeof(T))
      .Where(name => Convert.ToInt64(Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), name)) == value)
      .OrderBy(name => name));
  }
}

private static string LongAttributeName<T>(long value) where T : Enum {
  unchecked {
    return string.Join(" or ", Enum
      .GetNames(typeof(T))
      .Where(name => Convert.ToInt64(Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), name)) == value)
      .Select(name => typeof(T)
         .GetMember(name)
         .FirstOrDefault(mi => mi.DeclaringType == typeof(T)))
      .SelectMany(mi => mi.GetCustomAttributes<CategoryEnumAttribute>(false))
      .Select(attr => attr.Description) //TODO: Put the right property here
      .OrderBy(name => name));
  }
}

private static string[] LongNames<T>() where T : Enum {
  unchecked {
    return Enum
      .GetNames(typeof(T))
      .OrderBy(name => Convert.ToInt64(Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), name)))
      .ThenBy(name => name)
      .ToArray();
  }
}

private static string[] LongNamesCombined<T>() where T : Enum {
  unchecked {
    return Enum
      .GetNames(typeof(T))
      .GroupBy(name => Convert.ToInt64(Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), name)))
      .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
      .Select(group => string.Join(" or ", group.OrderBy(name => name)))
      .ToArray();
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
// Single Value
Console.Write(LongName<MyEnum>(1));
// Single Value attributes
Console.Write(LongAttributeName<MyEnum>(1));
// All Values (array with 4 items)
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", LongNames<MyEnum>())); 
// All Values combined (array with 2 items)
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", LongNamesCombined<MyEnum>()));
```

**Outcome:**

```
Red or Strong
Color or Attributes      # <- Depends on implementation
Red, Strong, Blue, Weak
Red or Strong, Blue or Weak
```

Comment: Yes that works, but I also need to know its attributes

Comment: @Delynith: You can exploit the same idea (parsing names) for attributes as well as names (please, see `LongAttributeName` method)